# JavaScript intervires with page loading wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, loading

So I’m quite new to WordPress developing and I’m trying to implement MixClouds API into this website. I’ve managed to make the images load the Mixcloud URL via custom fields in WordPress. When you click on an image, it will load the song into the MixCloud widget that is I have inserted into the function.php of the theme.

https://gamma.itmotr-radio.com/shows

That part works perfectly. Which took me a while, but now the part that I can’t figure out. The script for the Mixcloud Widget needs to be on the entire site. But since the script is loaded, and you want to go to another page, the widget will keep playing (which is good!!) but the page itself stays totally black, none of the pages codes will load, but the widget is still there.

I think this has something to do with the script, and that it stop loading the page itself after the script is loaded. Can someone help? I also tried to put the script in one of the .PHP files like footer.php and header.php. but this doesn't help as well.

— MixCloud Script —

```html
<script src="//widget.mixcloud.com/media/js/widgetApi.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="//widget.mixcloud.com/media/js/footerWidgetApi.js" async>
    {"feed": "/itmotr-radio/"}
</script>
```

loads the URL from

```html
<div ... data-mixcloud-play-button="<?php
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mixcloud-url', true);
?>"></pr>
```

which can be found in the blog/shows page of the website.

If anyone knows how to make the WordPress page loading work again, while this script is still there, please let me know :)

Comment: Are you loading the external js in the footer or header files? Try changing it's position. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: looks like you may have a conflict; best to show a little more context (add more code to question)

Comment: @docholiday I'm loading the external JS in the function.php of the theme that I use in Wordpress. I have one ERROR: " Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.mixcloud.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://gamma.itmotr-radio.com').
n @ footerWidgetApi.js:1" but I don't think it is causing the loading error?

Comment: It seems like the script is executing too soon. Why are you putting it in the functions.php file? I think you should create a child theme, and load that js file in the footer.

Comment: @docholiday I have created a child theme, and I'm working within that child theme already. So it should load anything else prior to the script